# Will a table lock prevent row locking

Tags: mysql, sql, locking, alter-table

I have a table with more than 160 milion of entries, which has a wrong table engine, so I'm going to change the engine. 
When I do this without any preparation, I get a error due to my buffer size, because of too many row locks

```
mysql> ALTER TABLE foobar ENGINE=MyISAM;
ERROR 1206 (HY000): The total number of locks exceeds the lock table size
```

I now want to lock the whole table before this action and unlock the whole table afterwards.

```
mysql> LOCK TABLES foobar WRITE;
```

My question: Does the mysql server notice that a table lock is already active and skip the row locks or has it locked the table and will now also lock every row again and I will experience the same error again?

I am also open for any other sugestions how to change the engine of such a big (and bigger) table the quickest way :)

Comment: Check pt-online-schema-change tool. It should  workaround your problem too. But MyISAM... you don't care about your data, do you? :)

Comment: thanks for the advise about the tool! I'd prefer changing the engine without any third party tool but maybe there is no other way to solve this issue. btw: every tool does its job ey ;) - so does MyISAM. So to answer your question: no, in this case I actually don't, its actually a cache table, but anyway... The question is more about the background processes and understanding if mysql skips row locking if table locking is already active :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can run an experiment:

In the first session run:

```
mysql> LOCK TABLE foobar WRITE;
mysql> ALTER TABLE foobar ENGINE=MyISAM;
```

In a second session (i.e. open a second terminal window), run:

```
mysql> SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS\G
```

Down in the TRANSACTIONS section, you'll find your ALTER thread in progress:

```
---TRANSACTION 69638, ACTIVE 45 sec fetching rows
mysql tables in use 1, locked 1
14626 lock struct(s), heap size 1898936, 5145657 row lock(s)
```

Whoah! It's creating many individual row locks, in spite of the LOCK TABLE in effect.

(That's just an example; you'll see the number of row locks increasing over time as the ALTER TABLE works through your table.)

---

So you need to guarantee space for a large number of row locks.

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/innodb-error-codes.html says:

> - 1206 (ER_LOCK_TABLE_FULL)
>
>   The total number of locks exceeds the amount of memory InnoDB devotes to managing locks. To avoid this error, **increase the value of `innodb_buffer_pool_size`.** Within an individual application, a workaround may be to break a large operation into smaller pieces. For example, if the error occurs for a large `INSERT`, perform several smaller `INSERT` operations.

(emphasis mine)

Also read [How much memory Innodb locks really take?](http://www.mysqlperformanceblog.com/2006/07/13/how-much-memory-innodb-locks-really-take/)

> Innodb row level locks are implemented by having special lock table, located in the buffer pool where small record allocated for each hash and for each row locked on that page bit can be set. This in theory can give overhead as low as few bits per row.

So locking 160 million rows requires about 60-80MB of space in the lock table. Your buffer pool might be too small to hold that.

The default size of the InnoDB buffer pool was only 8MB in MySQL 5.1.27 and earlier. The default was increased to 128MB in MySQL 5.1.28.

---

Re your comment:

> every tool does its job ey ;) - so does MyISAM

MyISAM doesn't support Atomicity, Consistency, Isolation, or Durability. Other than that, it's great. :-)

Comment: Thanks for the help! My server version is `5.5.35-0+wheezy1-log`, so should have had enough... I just assigned `1G` though, lets see how this will work. About the comment: Yeah we really don't need `ACID` with this table, we might even empty it and rebuild the cache if this won't work out, so for us MyISAM is great :)

Comment: Okay, if you don't need transactions and the data is easily rebuilt when it becomes corrupted, and you like it that [MyISAM has worse performance](http://www.mysqlperformanceblog.com/2007/01/08/innodb-vs-myisam-vs-falcon-benchmarks-part-1/), then go for it!

Comment: Bill, did you try auto_commit = 0 first so that the table lock isn't immediately released?

Comment: @MarcusAdams, explicit table locks aren't limited to a single transactions. They stay in effect until you explicitly UNLOCK TABLES or your session ends.

Comment: I suppose I was confused by this: "All InnoDB locks held by a transaction are released when the transaction is committed or aborted. Thus, it does not make much sense to invoke LOCK TABLES on InnoDB tables in autocommit=1 mode because the acquired InnoDB table locks would be released immediately." from [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/innodb-restrictions.html).

Comment: @MarcusAdams, aha, but the table locks created by LOCK TABLES are set (and presumably released) by the MySQL layer, above the storage engine layer. Cf. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/innodb-locks-set.html (in the last bullet at the bottom of the page).

Comment: the experiment really answers the question, thank you!

Comment: Is 60-80MB of space would pertain to the amount of `innodb_buffer_pool_size`?

Comment: @javiniar.leonard, yes, Innodb stores locks in a special internal "lock table" which uses the same memory allocated by the `innodb_buffer_pool_size`. See https://mrothouse.wordpress.com/2006/10/20/mysql-error-1206/

Answer (score 1):

Normally, if your InnoDB buffer pool isn't large enough to hold row locks for all the rows in a table (as is sometimes necessary), you increase the InnoDB buffer pool size ([innodb_buffer_pool_size](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/innodb-parameters.html#sysvar_innodb_buffer_pool_size)).

Try increasing your innodb_buffer_pool_size to 128 MB.

If you're still having problems, you can always try creating the new MyISAM table then do `INSERT INTO ... SELECT FROM ...` to copy your data from the InnoDB table to the MyISAM one. You can copy the rows in chunks to reduce the row locks.

Comment: Thanks for the advise, copying the data from the old to the new table(with the correct engine) is the next step I'll try out if the `ALTER` still fails. I just thought that mysql does the same thing internally(copying via a temp table on the `ALTER`), so where would be the point to do it by hand... But maybe I was wrong and that's the solution ;) I'll see tomorrow.

Comment: InnoDB does create *shared* locks on the rows from the origin table during `INSERT INTO ... SELECT FROM ...`. For example, this can cause the replication thread on a slave to be blocked, while you're inserting lots of rows into temp tables.